# Imagemagick convert command returning error code 4 when used with PHP

Tags: php, windows, imagemagick, wamp

I am executing ImageMagick command using PHP `exec` function, it returns an `error code 4` which `probably` mean `The system cannot open the file` when however I run same command in Windows terminal it works fine. I am using this below command to resize the image:

In terminal(working fine)

```
convert -resize 150^% ad.png res_ad.png
```

In PHP (returning error code 4)

```
exec(escapeshellcmd("convert -resize 150% $file_name.png res_$file_name.png"), $output2, $return2)
```

PS: I have checked and path of the image is correct.

Comment: Can you try it this way?

$command = 'convert -resize 150% "'.$file_name.'.png" "res_'.$file_name.'.png"';
exec($command, $output2, $return2);

Comment: @JosMarRivera I tried it and getting same error. Anyway, the command you have provided is same as mine.

Comment: Issue Resolved: I read somewhere on the internet: On Windows, there are several convert.exe commands, all of which are in the PATH. So you must specify the path to the right convert.exe executable.
Solution: Added "magick" before command and it worked fine, for example: magick convert ad.png -resize 150% res_ad_png and it worked fine

Comment: great @D555, I'm happy for you!

Answer (score 0):

I have only had a 1 or 0 returned from Imagemagick using php so I do not know were the 4 is coming from.

I have used similar code to yours but have never used escapeshellcmd in the exec. The exec is calling an external program and I am not sure you can use it there.

Try( notice the input image comes right after the convert in most cases ):

```
exec("convert $file_name.png -resize 150% res_$file_name.png");
```

You can validate your input and output image filenames before sending them to exec()

Different error reporting:

```
$array=array();
echo "<pre>";
exec("convert $file_name.png -resize 150% res_$file_name.png 2>&1", $array); 
echo "<br>".print_r($array)."<br>"; 
echo "</pre>";
```

Comment: Unfortunately it did not work. Even if I write file name after -resize it works properly in command line but it is not working in php script

Comment: Have you tried running the code on an image in the same folder and saving to the same folder. Using hard coded input output image names? I have also added some more code with a different way to output errors. It is recommended putting the input filename straight after convert and in V7 that is a must. It will work most of the time where you have it but depending on the options used it could fail.

Comment: Did you get any error messages from Bonzo's commands? If not, then it is likely your PHP environment. Perhaps you do not have permissions to use exec()?

Comment: @Bonzo I tried your new way of error reporting and also changed the order of the parameter as per your suggestion: It printed: Array ( [0] => Invalid Parameter - -resize ). It is bit strange because same command works perfectly in windows terminal. It is definitely not exec permission issue.

Comment: As I say I would try hard coding everything in the same folder to prove it will work. Also change the -resize to 150x150 to remove any possible errors with paths, spaces in filenames and the % may need escaping.

Comment: I think Bonzo is suggesting 150x150%. The % may need escaping and that is OS dependent. You can also try "150x150%".